# jQuery: select all elements except next

Tags: jquery

I have the following markup:

```
<!-- first marker -->
<div class="marker"></div>
<div class="tooltip">
    <p>My tooltip content"</p>
</div>

<!-- second marker -->
<div class="marker"></div>
<div class="tooltip">
    <p>My tooltip content"</p>
</div> 

<!-- repeating..... -->
```

and the following jQuery javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".marker").hover(function(event){
        $('.tooltip').hide();
        $(this).next('.tooltip').slideDown('fast');
    });

});
```

How can I modify this script so that on hover all other open div.tooltips hide except for the next one? Currently it tries to hide all.

Comment: You are missing a closing `'`

Comment: What do you mean by "next", exactly?

Comment: James: thanks, have updated my post.

Comment: I know the current code is correct, but I want to improve it so that instead of hiding all '.tooltip', it hides all EXCEPT the next div.tooltip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `not` function to omit a particular element

```
$(".marker").hover(function(event){
    var nextEl = $(this).next("div.tooltips");
    $('.tooltip').not(nextEl).hide();
    $(this).next('.tooltip').slideDown('fast');
});
```

**EDIT**

Also, you'll likely want to also pass a second function to `hover` so that things clean up when the hover ends:

```
$(".marker").hover(function(event){
    var nextEl = $(this).next("div.tooltips");
    $('.tooltip').not(nextEl).hide();
    $(this).next('.tooltip').slideDown('fast');
}, function() {
    $('.tooltip').hide();
});
```

Comment: perfect!! Just what I was looking for!

Comment: When using .hover, you need to implement callback for both mouse enter and mouse leave, else you will end up seeing 2 tooltips open when you hover faster between div's.

Comment: @Adam Rackis: Also I believe you don't need 'var nextEl = $(this).next("div.tooltips");' and '$('.tooltip').not(nextEl).hide();' If you implementing mouseleave.

Comment: @SKS - *probably* unless these tooltips are being shown elsewhere, but you're probably right

Answer (score 1):

Below code should do the trick,

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".marker").hover(function(event){
        //$('.tooltip').hide();
        $(this).next('.tooltip').eq(0).slideDown('fast');
    }, function (event) {
        $('.tooltip').hide();
    });

});
```

**Note:** You need to implement the mouseleave function for proper show/hide tooltip

Answer (score 0):

I know there is a not() function to exclude some elements. I never used it but it must be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have so you can get it by an id or something else? cause there is the :not() selector in jQuery

http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you are using `hover` with one function, which means it it attempting to show a tooltip on `mouseover` and `mouseout`. If you supply two functions, one showing, one hiding the tooltip, it works:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".marker").hover(function(event){
        $('.tooltip').hide();
        $(this).next('.tooltip').slideDown('fast');
    },
    function(event){
        $('.tooltip').slideUp('fast');
    });
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/JYSmK/)